# Rearranging table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want reorder table rows using JavaScript .

for example take the following dummy table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>D1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to do this in JavaScript without using jQuery.  I want to show the A1,B1,C1,D1.. row as the first row and then 1,2,3,4 row and then A,B,C,D row.

I know that there will be some wait time on the client side but I need to do it in the client side. Is there some generic solution to do this, for any number of rows?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?  As far as a generic solution in JS, it depends what you mean by generic (you gave one example, but didn't say how it should be extrapolated).  But this isn't hard at all once you know the JS DOM methods.  If you're still lost, give the signature of the function you're trying to implement, and we'll try to help.

Comment: @Matthew since the question implies this has nothing to do with c#, I think this may be yet another case where the asker just tagged with the technologies being used on the project. I removed the c# tag.

Comment: @Matthew and Rex...

I tagged it under c# not becuase of the project but assuming that max people who use javascript would use C#. I just wanted this question to reach more no of people.
I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: @Ben: Your assumption is probably incorrect. In any case, you should only tag questions with relevant tags, otherwise people tend to get annoyed with you :)

Comment: Alright... I will add appropriate tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to solve this in Javascript is:

Give the Tr.. a unique name.  for eg: X_Y,X_Z,A_Y,A_Z

Now add a hidden lable or text Box which gives the sorting order from the server i.e  When the page renders I want to sort it  All the Tr's that have a ID starting with A should come first and All the Z's should come second.

```
<asp:label id="lblFirstSortOrder" runat="server" style="display:none;">A,X</label>
<asp:label id="lblSecondSortOrder" runat="server" style="display:none;">Z,Y</label>
```

When the page renders..the order should be A_Z,A_Y,X_Z,X_Y

Before Rendering this is table that comes from the aspx file:

```
<table>
<tr id='Tr_Heading'>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>B</td>
</tr>
<tr id="Tr_X_Y">
  <td>GH</td>
  <td>GH1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_X_Z">
  <td>HU</td>
  <td>HU1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_A_Z">
  <td>JI</td>
  <td>JI1</td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_A_Y">
  <td>JI</td>
  <td>JI1</td>
</tr>
```

Script:

```
function SortAndArrange()
{
var firstList = document.getElementById('lblFirstSortOrder').value;
var secondList = document.getElementById('lblSecondSortOrder').value;
var firstTypes = new Array();
firstTypes = firstList.split(',');
var secondLists = new Array();
secondLists = secondList.split(',');
var refNode = document.getElementById('Tbl_' + firstTypes[0] + "_" + secondTypes[0]);
for (var i = 0; i<firstTypes.length; i++)
{
  for (var j = 0; j< secondTypes.length;j++)
  {
     var TrName = 'Tbl_'+firstTypes[i]+'_'+secondTypes[j];
     var FirstSecondTrs = document.getElementById(TrName);
     if (FirstSecondTrs)
     {
       FirstSecondTrs.parentNode.removeChild(FirstSecondTrs);        
       insertAfter(refNode,FirstSecondTrs);
       refNode = FirstSecondTrs;
     }
  }
 }
}
function insertAfter( referenceNode, newNode )
{   
 referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore( newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling );
}
```

I hope you guys get the idea.. for me the sorting order will always come from the server and not from the user of the page...

Thanks a Lot for all the answers.. Apprecite it. Helped me get to this solution.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 13):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to take the last row and make it the first row, pushing down the rest. This should do it:

```
<table id="mytable">
...
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tbl = document.getElementById('mytable');
    var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var firstRow = rows[0];
    var lastRow = rows[rows.length];
    firstRow.parentNode.insertBefore(lastRow.parentNode.removeChild(lastRow), firstRow);
</script>
```

Assuming your table does not have nested tables. At which point this would need to be a little smarter. This also assumes you're not using TBODY and THEAD nodes. But I'm sure you can get the idea and enhance it from there.

Comment: This may not work because browsers insert TBODY into the DOM regardless of markup, and IE is not smart enough to properly reparent a row from TABLE to TBODY when you use DOM operations.

Comment: @levik actually my script does allow for nodes between the TABLE and TR element, such as TBODY. It does so by always referring to the TR's parent, whatever that might be.

Comment: @Rex and @levik... I found a very eligant solution to do this... which is much more generic and doesnt have to worry about other things

Comment: @Ben please post it as an answer then!

Comment: @Rex I have added my solution... let me know what you think about my eligant solution.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: To future readers: This should be the accepted answer, no offense but the accepted answer is by no means elegant or more generic, it just adds overhead via unique names and hidden labels/text-boxes and is rather an ugly workaround..

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
var table = ...; // Get reference to table (by ID or other means)
var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
lastRow.parent.insertBefore(table.rows[0], lastRow);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use table.getElementsByTagName("tr") to get the rows.

Comment: That will (wrongly) return any rows of nested tables - which you don't want.